# Failed to compile OpenGTS

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I'm having trouble compiling OpenGTS on windows 7. I have followed OpenGTS Installation and Configuration PDF but still with no luck. I'm using:

```
java: jdk7u51 ant : apache-ant-1.7.0 tomcat : tomcat 8 mysql : mysql5.5.20 mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar javax.mail.jar
```

I have configured `JAVA_HOME, GTS_HOME, CATALINA_HOME, MYSQL_HOME, ANT_HOME`,
and added the them to `path`.

```
 [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBSelect<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBSelect
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\RoleRecord.java:38: warning: [ra
wtypes] found raw type: DBRecord
    [javac] public class RoleRecord<RT extends DBRecord>
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBRecord<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBRecord
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\RoleRecord.java:60: warning: [ra
wtypes] found raw type: DBRecord
    [javac]     public static abstract class RoleKey<RT extends DBRecord>
    [javac]                                                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBRecord<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBRecord
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\tables\Geozone.java:1768: warnin
g: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, Geozone, instead of
by an expression
    [javac]         if (!this.supportsCorridor()) {
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\tables\Geozone.java:1812: warnin
g: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, Geozone, instead of
by an expression
    [javac]         if (!this.supportsCorridor()) {
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\WorkHours.java:486: warning: [st
atic] static method should be qualified by type name, WorkHours, instead of by a
n expression
    [javac]                 int   frTod = this.convertHourMinuteToTOD(frTm,false
);
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\WorkHours.java:487: warning: [st
atic] static method should be qualified by type name, WorkHours, instead of by a
n expression
    [javac]                 int   toTod = this.convertHourMinuteToTOD(toTm,true
);
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\DCServerConfig.java:59: warning:
 [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
    [javac]     implements Comparable
    [javac]                ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\DCServerConfig.java:385: warning
: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]             Class dbfc = dbf.getTypeClass();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\DCServerConfig.java:3679: warnin
g: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]                 Class cpClass = Class.forName(cpClassName);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\DCServerFactory.java:2187: warni
ng: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]     private static Class      ClassUnassignedDevices      = null;
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:458
: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]                     Class pllClass = Class.forName(CLASS_PrivateLabe
lLoader);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:482
: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]     public static Class getInstanceClass()
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:172
7: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]             Class pwhClass = Class.forName(phClassName);  // ClassNo
tFoundException
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:176
5: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, BasicPrivat
eLabelLoader, instead of by an expression
    [javac]         boolean active = this._isAttributeActive(activeStr,rpName);
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:184
7: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]             Class rgpClass = Class.forName(rpClassName);  // ClassNo
tFoundException
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:190
5: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, BasicPrivat
eLabelLoader, instead of by an expression
    [javac]         boolean active   = this._isAttributeActive(activeStr,gpName)
;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:195
8: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]             Class gpClass = Class.forName(gpClassName);  // ClassNot
FoundException
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:200
1: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, BasicPrivat
eLabelLoader, instead of by an expression
    [javac]         if (!this._isAttributeActive(active,mpName)) {
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:205
1: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]             Class mpClass = Class.forName(mpClassName);  // ClassNot
FoundException
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:230
2: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: OrderedMap
    [javac]         OrderedMap pushpinMap,
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class OrderedMap<K,V>
    [javac]   where K,V are type-variables:
    [javac]     K extends Object declared in class OrderedMap
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class OrderedMap
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\BasicPrivateLabelLoader.java:273
2: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]                 Class labelClass = Class.forName(className);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\GroupRecord.java:38: warning: [r
awtypes] found raw type: DBRecord
    [javac] public class GroupRecord<RT extends DBRecord>
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBRecord<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBRecord
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\GroupRecord.java:63: warning: [r
awtypes] found raw type: DBRecord
    [javac]     public static abstract class GroupKey<RT extends DBRecord>
    [javac]                                                      ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBRecord<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBRecord
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\tables\DeviceGroup.java:676: war
ning: [rawtypes] found raw type: DBSelect
    [javac]     protected static DBSelect _getDeviceListSelect(String acctId, St
ring groupId, long limit)
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBSelect<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBSelect
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\tables\DeviceGroup.java:715: war
ning: [rawtypes] found raw type: DBSelect
    [javac]         DBSelect dsel = DeviceGroup._getDeviceListSelect(acctId, gro
upId, -1L);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBSelect<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBSelect
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\tables\DeviceGroup.java:770: war
ning: [rawtypes] found raw type: DBSelect
    [javac]         DBSelect dsel = DeviceGroup._getDeviceListSelect(acctId, gro
upId, limit);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBSelect<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBSelect
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\HierarchyRecord.java:38: warning
: [rawtypes] found raw type: DBRecord
    [javac] public abstract class HierarchyRecord<RT extends DBRecord>
    [javac]                                                  ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBRecord<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBRecord
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\HierarchyRecord.java:89: warning
: [rawtypes] found raw type: DBRecord
    [javac]     public static abstract class HierarchyKey<RT extends DBRecord>
    [javac]                                                          ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBRecord<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBRecord
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\HierarchyRecord.java:162: warnin
g: [rawtypes] found raw type: HierarchyRecord
    [javac]     public static <RT extends HierarchyRecord> TreeNode/*<RT>*/ read
Hiearchy(DBFactory<RT> dbFact, Account acct)
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class HierarchyRecord<RT>
    [javac]   where RT is a type-variable:
    [javac]     RT extends DBRecord declared in class HierarchyRecord
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\ParseEvent.java:384: warning: [r
awtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]         Class  fmtClass   = RTConfig.getClass(ARG_FORMAT , null);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\dmtp\EventTemplate.java:75: warn
ing: [rawtypes] found raw type: Map
    [javac]     private static Map fieldMap = ListTools.toMap("getCode", new Fie
ldType[] {
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Map<K,V>
    [javac]   where K,V are type-variables:
    [javac]     K extends Object declared in interface Map
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface Map
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\tables\GroupList.java:217: warni
ng: [rawtypes] found raw type: DBSelect
    [javac]     protected static DBSelect _getUserListSelect(String acctId, Stri
ng groupId)
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBSelect<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBSelect
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\tables\GroupList.java:262: warni
ng: [rawtypes] found raw type: DBSelect
    [javac]         DBSelect dsel = GroupList._getUserListSelect(acctId, groupId
);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBSelect<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBSelect
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\tables\UserDevice.java:242: warn
ing: [rawtypes] found raw type: DBSelect
    [javac]     protected static DBSelect _getDeviceSelect(String acctId, String
 userId)
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBSelect<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBSelect
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\db\tables\UserDevice.java:284: warn
ing: [rawtypes] found raw type: DBSelect
    [javac]         DBSelect dsel = UserDevice._getDeviceSelect(acctId, userId);

    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class DBSelect<gDBR>
    [javac]   where gDBR is a type-variable:
    [javac]     gDBR extends DBRecord declared in class DBSelect
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\geocoder\geonames\GeoNames.java:124
4: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Map
    [javac]     private String appendAddressKey(StringBuffer sb, Map addrProps,
String key, boolean suffixComma)
    [javac]                                                      ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Map<K,V>
    [javac]   where K,V are type-variables:
    [javac]     K extends Object declared in interface Map
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface Map
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\geocoder\geonames\GeoNames.java:148
0: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Map
    [javac]     private String appendPostalCodeElement(StringBuffer sb, Map code
Props, String key, int maxLen, boolean suffixComma)
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Map<K,V>
    [javac]   where K,V are type-variables:
    [javac]     K extends Object declared in interface Map
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface Map
    [javac] C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\src\org\opengts\geocoder\tinygeocoder\TinyGeocoder.
java:282: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, Tiny
Geocoder, instead of by an expression
    [javac]         String result = this._getPageResponse(url, timeoutMS);
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] 64 warnings
     [copy] Copying 45 files to C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\build
      [jar] Building jar: C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\build\lib\gtsdb.jar
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\build\lib

optjars:

tomcat.home:
     [echo] 'CATALINA_HOME' is defined - C:\Program Files\Apache Software Founda
tion\Tomcat 8.0;

tomcat.env:

tools:
     [echo] Tools ...
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\build

BUILD FAILED
C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\build.xml:2053: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tom
cat 8.0; not found.

Total time: 50 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Those Java compiler messages are only warnings, so you can just ignore them.

Looks like the actual error is that script failed to find Tomcat:

> ```
> BUILD FAILED C:\OpenGTS_2.5.3\build.xml:2053: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0; not found.
> ```

Are you sure you specified correct path?